# Why doesn't push() function work with fs in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function, push

data.txt:

```
xxxx1;yyyy1
xxxx2;yyyy2
xxxx3;yyyy3
xxxx4;yyyy4
xxxx5;yyyy5
```

Here is how my data.txt looks like and when I run the following function:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var x = [];
var y = [];
function pushdata(){
  fs.readFile('data.txt', (err, data) => {
    data = data.toString().split("\n");
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      x.push(data[i].split(';')[0]);
      y.push(data[i].split(';')[1]);
    }
  });
}
pushdata()
console.log(x, y);
```

The output is:

```
[] []
```

Instead of:

```
[ 'xxxx1', 'xxxx2', 'xxxx3', 'xxxx4', 'xxxx5' ] [ 'yyyy1', 'yyyy2', 'yyyy3', 'yyyy4', 'yyyy5' ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for completion. You log the arrays before anything has been pushed into them

```
var fs = require('fs');
var x = [];
var y = [];
function pushdata(done){
  fs.readFile('data.txt', (err, data) => {
    data = data.toString().split("\n");
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      x.push(data[i].split(';')[0]);
      y.push(data[i].split(';')[1]);
    }
    done()
  });
}

pushdata(function () {
  console.log(x, y); 
})
```

Comment: Isn't there anything I can do other than do what you've done or using setTimeout() ?

Comment: @uhbc yeah, you can use setTimeout. however... how long should you tell it to wait?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'll use the x and y values in a for loop right after I run the pushdata() function.